# Retrieve all records of specific month in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking for sql query that can bring records of specific month from all years of record. i.e., I have record from 2001 till date...I want to bring record of **May** from all years.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the MySQL function 'MONTH'...

```
WHERE MONTH(some_date) = 5
```